# Jupyter nbextensions directory

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to add code snippets to the Jupyter notebook nbextensions, it says in the documentation to add the code snippet to /nbextensions/snippets/snippets.json but the file does not exist. I'm using a conda virtual environment.

Comment: Can you link to the specific documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\nbextensions\snippets`.

You can do a search for `snippets.json` on your PC to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As documentation to snippet extension says, `snippets.json` file can be located using:

```sh
$(jupyter --data-dir)/nbextensions/snippets/snippets.json
```

See the readme from the [extension docs](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/snippets/README.html).